# Best way to replace all occurences of a character in a string after the first occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently doing this:

```
teststring = "abc-def-ghi-jkl"
pos = teststring.find('-')
newstr = "{}-{}".format(teststring[0:pos], teststring[pos + 1:].replace('-', '_'))
```

This seems unnecessarily clunky. Is there a more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Not sure if it would be an improvement but you can use .split instead of .find, e.g., `a,b = teststring.split('-', 1)` then you won't have to do all those slicing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.split`:

```
pre, post = teststring.split('-', 1)
newstr = pre + '-' + post.replace('-', '_')
```

Like your original solution, this only works if there's at least one `-` in the string. You can use variable-length argument unpacking to fix this:

```
*pre, post = 'asdfd--saf'.split('-', 1)
newstr = '-'.join(pre + [post.replace('-', '_')])
```

Now `pre` will be either the prefix or an empty list if there are no dashes. `post` is always the full suffix, with or without dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a regex:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=-)(.*?)-', r'\1_', 'abc-def-ghi-jkl')
'abc-def_ghi_jkl'
```

It uses a positive lookbehind to match the `-` character only if another `-` character appears before it in the string. This is a bit more complicated than the simplest solution using `split`, but it works correctly even when the input string doesn't contain any `-` characters.

Comment: `\1` means all of the characters matching the `(.*?)` group. Because a positive lookbehind can only be for a fixed-length string, the regex has to capture all the characters between the two `-` characters, so effectively in the string `abc-def-ghi` it matches `def-` and replaces it with `def_`.